# Updated Ubuntu 14.04 now after putting in password it doesn't load anything else

Tags: updates

Updated Ubuntu 14.04 today. (Was 14.04 before aswell I believe).
I can get to the log in screen but it hasn't remembered my display settings.
I type in my password- all good. Then it just sits on my screen saver doesn't pull up the task bar or anything. 
Not a clue what to do or what the problem is. 
I can access the GNOME terminal fine.

Comment: I've been trying solutions to problems which seem to be the same. I keep getting told there's No_Default_Display set. It tries to set it to =:0 then it says unable to use that display

Comment: Sounds like your issue is identical to mine.  >> http://askubuntu.com/questions/590370/14-04-to-14-04-2-upgrade-gui-disappears

Comment: I just had to do a full reinstall

Answer (score 0):

*This Probleme accured in unity configuration try to reset unity by typing*

`unity-reset`

*The second method might not work in all cases but it can be used in case the above method doesn't work for you or you simply want to try and reset Unity and Compiz manually.*

*Firstly, install dconf-tools:*

`sudo apt-get install dconf-tools`

*Since Compiz in Ubuntu 14.04, 13.10 and 13.04 is using Gsettings (dconf), you can reset Compiz and Unity by using the following command:*

`dconf reset -f /org/compiz/`

*The old "unity --reset" command used to restart Unity too, while the command above doesn't. So to restart Unity after running the above command, use:*

`setsid unity`

*You can also run the following command to see the Compiz settings you have:*

`dconf dump /org/compiz/`

_I recomend to install unity tweak tool

`sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool`